# Vagrant up Connection refused

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm trying to vagrant up and getting the connection refused error. Not sure what I need to do here. But when I put that whole path in the browser, i can download the .box. But when I do that in the vagrant file, I get the below error

```
Bringing machine 'acs' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'web' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'db' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> acs: Box 'ubuntu/trusty64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    acs: Box Provider: virtualbox
    acs: Box Version: >= 0
==> acs: Loading metadata for box 'ubuntu/trusty64'
    acs: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/trusty64
==> acs: Adding box 'ubuntu/trusty64' (v20170512.0.0) for provider: virtualbox
    acs: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64/versions/20170512.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Failed to connect to cloud-images.ubuntu.com port 80: Connection refused
```

Here is my vagrant file

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.define "acs" do |acs|
    acs.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    acs.vm.hostname = "acs"
    acs.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  end

  config.vm.define "web" do |web|
    web.vm.box= "nrel/CentOS-6.5-x86_64"
    web.vm.hostname = "web"
    web.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.20"
    web.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  end

  config.vm.define "db" do |db|
    db.vm.box = "nrel/CentOS-6.5-x86_64"
    db.vm.hostname = "db"
    db.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.30"
  end


end
```

Comment: Do you have any proxy servers configured in your browser?

Comment: No there is no proxy setup. I've checked my browsers. And by the way I'm on mac.